# Changing Dock Icon OSX and other Icons -SWIFT

Tags: xcode, macos

I have added 16x16,32x32,... etc icons to AppIcon in Assets.xcassets

I have few questions related to this

1. e.g.: what does 1x and 2x mean for 32X32 icon... I have put `32PX X 32PX` icon for both 1X and 2X and done the same for all icons.
   What should be the exact size of these icons.

2.Even after setting these icons,Icon is not changed in the Dock

Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the AppIcon on your Mac won't change after using the correct size you may have to clean the Xcode Project and rebuild it completely. You can do this under "Product" > "Clean build folder" (you have to press alt while in the menu) or simply press alt+shift+cmd+k

You can find the macOS AppIcon sizes in the '[Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/)' provided by Apple. The @2x icons are for retina displays like MacBookPro (since 2012) and iMac5k. The normal @1x icons are for good old non-retina displays.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Thanks.But This question is related to OSX..not IOS

Comment: What exactly does 2X mean ? For example 32x32 pixel image.

Comment: I dont know exactly, but I think @2x stands for 'double resolution'.

Answer (score -2):

It's related to the image sizes or pixel for different devices because different devices have different screen size as shown in attached images, Like iPhone 4,5,6 use 2x and 6+ use 3x.
Example: Suppose you have an image of size 32*32 for 1x,for 2x it will be 64*64 and for 3x it will be 96*96. 
[image]

Comment: The question is about macOS, not iOS.

Comment: rmaddy: This answer uses iOS devices as an *example* of differing asset scales, but it's still relevant and useful for macOS.